# Cant't login to desktop application on Remote Desktop Connetion using G1ANT robot

Tags: rpa, g1ant

I encountered a problem with the robot's work on Remote Desktop Connetion. As I have the virtual machine window opened or minimaized, the robot works perfectly on both the web and desktop applications. When I close the Desktop Connetion window and leave the working robot or schedule it to start at the specified time, unfortunately it is not able to log into the desktop application.
I think it might be a problem with waitfor.image command, it can't find a first picture confirming the opening of a desktop application:
waitfor.image image ‴♥sciezkaConfig\obrazki\uruchomiony.png‴ timeout 5000 errorcall BladLogowania

call Logowanie
procedure Logowanie
program C:\PartenonPRA\Apl\partenon.exe errorcall BladLogowania
call AddLog message ‴Uruchomiono aplikacje‴
waitfor.image image ‴♥sciezkaConfig\obrazki\uruchomiony.png‴ timeout 5000 errorcall BladLogowania
delay 2
call AddLog message ‴Zaleziono obrazek po uruchomieniu aplikacji‴
delay 2
keyboard login
keyboard ⋘TAB⋙
keyboard haslo
keyboard ⋘TAB⋙⋘ENTER⋙⋘ENTER⋙
call AddLog message ‴Wpisano haslo‴
delay 2
waitfor.image image ‴♥sciezkaConfig\obrazki\zalogowany.png‴ errorcall BladLogowania
call AddLog message ‴Znaleziono obrazek potwierdzajacy zalogawanie do aplikacji‴
end commandname procedure

Answer (score 2):

When you disconnect from your RD session the remote GUI is suspended.

G1ANT Robot has a winservice (Tools->Installers->RDP Controller) that you have to install and run in order to keep GUI of disconnected RD session alive (you will find more info in manual - https://manual.g1ant.com/appendices/rdp-controller.md). In order to start the winservice you have to have trial or production license.

Comment: I got a production license, and I've installed RDP Controller. RDP Service is running. I've tested it before on web aps and it works fine, even if I disconnect from my RD session. I have only problem with desktop app, it opens that application, but it can't find first picture. Logs indicate that the error occurs on this step: waitfor.image image ‴♥sciezkaConfig\obrazki\uruchomiony.png‴ timeout 5000 errorcall BladLogowania. It always makes a errorcall.

Comment: Does it work while you're connected with your RD client? Does it work with much longer timeout (5s might be not enough, because this command is relatively slow)?

Comment: It works while I'm connected with RD client and I've tried with different timeouts even 30 sec.

Comment: Please remove the ErrorCall part, this way you will know the details of the error. You will probably see a message that the image was not found, that is caused by the switch of resolution when RD guard winservice takes control over the session. If you want to see what exactly is happening perform a screenshot (i.e. `screenshot path ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\screenshot.png`) after a delay and during that delay close connection with RD - possibly the Robot will take the whole screen; in my test during the delay I minimized the Robot, closed RD client - and the image has been found.

Answer (score 0):

From my expirience there is some problem with RDP Controler. Try to run script below, and close the RDP connection, wait few secounds and conect again. If there is a gap bigger than 1 or 2 (There is a little gap because of connecting and disconnecting), RDP Controler is not working. This is the easiest way to check if it works properly.

```
program notepad
delay
for ♥i from 1 to 100
    keyboard ‴line: ♥i‴
    keyboard ⋘ENTER⋙
end for
```

Comment: This is caused by your app losing focus for a moment during the process of closing the connection. The RD winservice restores both the GUI and focus, but it takes about ~1s to do that.

Comment: Yep. I know that. It's totally fine for me.